# Can I Use a DLC Character on a Non-DLC PS3?

Tags: borderlands-series

Okay, so a couple friends and I all have *Borderlands 1 & 2* for the PS3, and I want to transfer some copies of my characters to their PS3. I already have a FAT32 formatted USB stick with my saves on it, etc.

The kind of thing I want to know is: can I transfer a DLC Character (i.e. Gaige or Kreig) from Borderlands 2 to their PS3 and use that character if they don't have any DLC? Can I use a non-DLC Character from either game if that character's level is above the default cap (i.e. above the default *Level 51* cap)? I don't think it's very likely that I'll be able to use DLC characters, but in some cases this is possible and I haven't yet found any answers online. Both of my games are *Game of the Year Edition*'s, with DLC stored on-disk for install, if that matters.

Also, if anyone knows, does my PS3's system need to be fully up-to-date in order for the copied saves to work? I have no internet, so my PS3 Software Version is behind theirs. Will this matter?

Answer (score 2):

I don t know how the game will handle your save file if you don t have DLC installed. BUT!

You have the DLC on disk, just bring them and install them on your friends's PS3, it is legal and will work.

This way, no need to worry about version of PS3 software, Game version, your friends will have the same DLC as you, and the save will work : )

(Also, your friends will get free DLC as long they don t erase it, so it s win-win, just a matter of taking ~10 min to install everything before playing).

If you had DLC on PSN, you could create a user on your friend's PS3, link to your account, and download the DLC, DLC work on all user, so they will have the DLC too.

Answer (score 0):

In order to play the DLC, their content must be on the PS3, so if he doesn't have the DLC installed it won't work

However as @DrakaSAN suggest, since you have the GoY edition, you can take your game and the install the DLCs to your friend console, since the GoY version don't have limitation in how many systems can be installed